# Neo4jRB: replicating accepts_nested_attributes_for functionality in ActiveNode?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'd love to be able to use Rails' native form infrastructure for managing nested relationships.

The [Changelog](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/c82285907a223456160145185f736f87359b7c71/CHANGELOG) makes reference to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but it does not seem to work.

Can I add properties to ActiveNode that are functions instead and manually manage the creation of related models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  I'd have to look deeper to say for sure, but since `ActiveNode` uses `ActiveModel`, it seems like setting a `<attribute>_attributes=` method might help.  See these links:

https://coderwall.com/p/kvsbfa/nested-forms-with-activemodel-model-objects

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Use-with-ActiveModel-compliant-models

I haven't tried it myself, but if that doesn't help then [open an issue](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/new) on the repo and we can take a look

Comment: Very interesting. I'm adding an `attr_accessor` and a `..._attributes` method to the model and using `fields_for` in the view. The nested fields don't appear. However, if I remove the  `..._attributes` method (but keep the `attr_accessor`), the fields appear. I believe I'm doing this right, I'll open an issue.